# Can only compile a VB6 DLL after opening a specific form in design mode

Tags: dll, vb6

ActiveX DLL project - running it or  Menu > File > Generate Dllname.dll... both produce the error message: *Error loading DLL*

However, **if I open a specific form in design mode then I can compile or run the project without problem.**

[image]

The form has a MSCAL.OCX v11 Calendar inside.

Note that if I open any other object (classes, forms, etc) continue with the error when try to Run/Compile. Is mandatory to open the frmDate.frm object if I want to Run/Compile the project.

I don't understand why it has this strange behavior and if there is a way to solve it.

Comment: Most likely one or more dependencies (like MSCAL) are not registered properly. But it is pretty strange that opening that form works around the problem.

Comment: @DavelnCaz - Thanks for editing. I'm still improving my english skills ;-) but certainly, this is the main problem. It is not making me crazy because I luckly have a way to work... I've tested from 3 different PCs (W7 & XP) and same result. I must open that frmDate.frm to compile

Comment: No problem - its an interesting VB6 situation and I hope some of the experts here see the question!

Answer (score 1):

Do you have proper appointed the startaup point of the project?
You can do this using this path above:
Go to “Project”->” Properties “, and in the “General” tab select the appropriate form from the “Startup Object” list box.